# Which market am I currently in?

Tags: google-play-store, localization

I am on an SGS2 purchased in Germany, located in the UK, sometimes using VPN to the US and have used Market Enabler to change Play Store codes in the past. By now I am confused as to what local market I am actually seeing when I open the app. How can I find out which Play Store I am being shown by Google?

In particular, I am confused because I am trying to purchase a UK app and receive the 'This item is not available in your country' message although I am in the UK and have a UK IP.

Edit: Could it be related to the registered credit card?

[This page](http://androidqueries.com/how-change-country-google-play-918.html) suggests to change the Google account globally.

Comment: This is the first time I hear anyone suggesting changing the location of your Google account. Note that  Google uses your credit card as well as your IP address and SIM card, so event if you are browsing the UK site, but don't have a UK-issued credit card, you can't purchase anything from there. A good way to tell between markets is by looking at the currency being displayed. (£ for UK)